# Merging two Xcode projects into one

Tags: ios, xcode

I am really stumped....

I have got two apps and i need to merge them into one.

how do i do this???

I need a home screen, swipe left (go to one app) and (swipe right) go to the other....

both apps are partially similar but have their own complexities about them.... so each app involves a login and uses Parse. (not sure if i should integrate both keys and id's and just use 1 data base or keep them separate as they are).

I need this to be formulated from 1 app that is downloaded from the app store instead of having two apps.

Please help me

Comment: So Simple. Create a third project have a single HomeScreen. And add the two xcode projects as you add a file not the folder but the xcode project file. Now add swipe action on HomeScreen and call respective controllers from each projects.. You can create two static libraries of your existing projects and add them into third one. See this http://blog.db-in.com/universal-framework-for-ios/

Comment: thankyou for your quick answer, I'm still stumped on how to actually do the integration, does anyone have a step by step tutorial or a video or something that may be useful, i am new to development and haven't grasped my head around everything yet, its been a raging 3 months but I'm getting there, any extra information and help would be so mostly appreciated. – rodger just now  edit

Answer (score 1):

Use workspace for doing this. The below links will help you for that.

1) [Xcode Workspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html)

2) [Creating a Workspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/creating_a_workspace.html)

Comment: thankyou for your quick answer, I'm still stumped on how to actually do the integration, does anyone have a step by step tutorial or a video or something that may be useful, i am new to development and haven't grasped my head around everything yet, its been a raging 3 months but I'm getting there, any extra information and help would be so mostly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a step by step tutorial for the exact thing you're looking to do because I would need more information on what the two apps are that you want to merge.  With that said, the functionality of swiping left and seeing the menu for App A and swiping right and seeing the menu for App B can be achieved by using this source code from GitHub https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu  There are two video tutorials there that walk you through how to implement it.

[image]