# about integrate project contained storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to integrate two project in one big project.The main project is calling iGardener and the sub-project is calling BBQ which have a storyboard calling "Main",I put the BBQ xcodeproj into iGardener as the image.

[image: img]

then make a storyboard reference in the iGardener storyboard like,

[image: img2]

when i run the project,it show,

> 2016-04-21 14:51:52.028 iGardener[18649:4274976] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could
>   not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)'

what's wrong,please help .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bundle is not loading in which your `main` storyboard is there.

Update as per comment :

You should use workspace to combine two projects. here i am sharing [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Creating_a_Workspace.html) and [stackoverflow link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398907/merging-two-xcode-projects-into-one) and [Stackoverflow link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797926/how-to-combine-two-apps-into-one-app-combine-two-projects)

hope this will help :)

Comment: thanks for your comment ,how to loading the bundle in there?please help,i find this solution for a few days,but have no idea....

Comment: thanks for your help,but i also cant solve it.i  rewrote the question in this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783325/integrate-two-project-and-cross-two-stroyboard  maybe it is more clean to explain what the problem is,thanks for your help.